# Angular unit test that calls a service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a very simple controller that has a scope variable that calls a service method to get populated. I'm trying to write the test make sure this variable gets populated, but i'm getting the error `Expected spy find to have been called.`

How can I write this unit test using spy for the service piece?

```
describe('StuffCtrl', function() {

    beforeEach(module('web'));

    var scope, ctrl, stuff;

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, Stuff) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      stuff = Stuff;
      ctrl = $controller('StuffCtrl', {$scope: scope, Stuff: stuff});
    }));

it('should fetch all the stuff', function() {

    // Mock the Stuff.find service
    spyOn(stuff, 'find');

    // ERROR ON THIS LINE: Expected spy find to have been called.
    expect(stuff.find).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(scope.stuff).toBeDefined();
  });
...
```

Controller

```
angular.module('web').controller('StuffCtrl',function($scope, $log, $routeParams, $location, Stuff){

  $scope.stuff = Stuff.find();

});
```

Stuff service

```
module.factory("Stuff", ['LoopBackResource', '$injector', function(Resource, $injector) {

  var R = Resource(
      urlBase + "/stuff/:id",
      { 'id': '@id' },
      {"find": {
          url: urlBase + "/stuffs",
          method: "GET",
          isArray: true,
        }
      });


    return R;
  }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
describe('StuffCtrl', function() {

    beforeEach(module('web'));

    var scope, ctrl, stuff;

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, Stuff) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      stuff = Stuff;
      // Mock the Stuff.find service
      spyOn(stuff, 'find');
      //you're instanciating the controller here so find will get executed.
      //you need to mock find before.
      ctrl = $controller('StuffCtrl', {$scope: scope});
    }));

it('should fetch all the stuff', function() {
    expect(stuff.find).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(scope.stuff).toBeDefined();
  });
...
```

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. So basically I need to call spy before I instantiate the controller, unless i have a function that I call in my controller. In that case I can call spyOn anytime before I call that controller function in my unit test. Right?

Comment: that's it, it's not obvious what $controller does but yeah, it instanciate your controller.